# MySQL connection taking too long?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database-performance

It seems that my code is taking a long time to open a connection, I have ran a few tests and the amount of time its taking is too high, previously it would loading in 500ms maximum.

The time is peaking at 2 whole seconds, is this normal behaviour for opening a MySQL connection in C#, or are my concers right? I'm judging this time with a stopwatch so its pretty accurate.

Lets benchmark it...

```
Startup 1 took: 1777ms
Startup 2 took: 1817ms
Startup 3 took: 1796ms
Startup 4 took: 1673ms
Startup 5 took: 1905ms
Startup 6 took: 1716ms
```

Here is the start of the bottleneck...

```
public DatabaseConnection Connection => new DatabaseConnection(_connectionString);

public bool ConnectionWorks()
{
    try
    {
        using (Connection)
        {
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For people interested in the DatabaseConnection class's constructor, here it is.

```
public DatabaseConnection(string connectionString)
{
    _connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    _command = _connection.CreateCommand();

    OpenConnection();
}
```

OpenConnection() method:

```
private void OpenConnection()
{
    if (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection already open.");
    }

    _connection.Open();
}
```

Connection string:

```
var connectionString = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    ConnectionLifeTime = 60 * 5,
    ConnectionTimeout = 30,
    Database = "testing",
    DefaultCommandTimeout = 30,
    Logging = false,
    MaximumPoolSize = 250,
    MinimumPoolSize = 10,
    Password = "********",
    Pooling = true,
    Port = 3306,
    Server = "127.0.0.1"
    UserID = "root"
};
```

I have done a little debugging and can see that the bottleneck is coming from `_connection.Open()`, all connections after the first are completed in under 20ms, which is considerably faster than the first connection...

Comment: Is your DB local or somewhere in cloudland?

Comment: It's on 127.0.0.1, so thats why I cant understand the time its taking... I've tried with another C# application and the difference is a lot..

Comment: Add your connection string (hidding sensitive content)

Comment: You say your other application is faster. So what's different? Is it using the same mysql driver? Same C# framework? Although the framework shouldn't be making a difference. Maybe restart mysql, it could be holding open connections or memory

Comment: @Gusman I have added my connection string. Steve, restarting MySQL doesn't help at all.

Comment: This is very strange, you are pooling the connections so those should be reused. Are you using the latest Mysql connector version?

Comment: @Gusman yes I am, I am using version 6.10.5.0

Comment: I've debugged it a little, and I've found out the bottleneck is on `_connection.Open()` in DatabaseConnection class. All the connections after the first one are taking less than 20ms (probably as they're pooling?)

Comment: Every time you use `Connection` it's going to create an new connection.  You should be doing something like `using(var conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))` instead.  Don't try to pool the connections yourself.

Comment: I'm not trying to pool them myself, why would you even suggest that? Nowhere in my code I am pooling connections.

Comment: Once you are connected, how long does `SELECT 1` (or some other trivial query) take?

Comment: Do you have timings for non-pooled connections?

Comment: @RickJames they are the ones in the question, the ones labeld "Startup 1 took.." etc... querys take a matter of milliseconds, not even 100ms nowhere near the amount of time a connection takes.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle's Connector/NET provider has a [known bug #80030](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80030) that can make the first connection to a server very slow.

I recommend switching to [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector), an OSS alternative that fixes this bug, is higher-performance overall, and offers true async I/O.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your hardware will be very relevance to the performance of any call, so how long should a call take, is a meaningless question.

Establishing database connections is generally a slow process, which is why connection pooling and connection reuse is a common technique.

Profiling, rather than stopwatching will give you a better idea of your bottlenecks.

Comment: I understand that, but another C# application also trying to make a connection is only taking 1 second max, which is half the time my question's application is taking.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code, and opening several connections sequentially.
It could be .Net startup influencing you call.